# List actors by genres of films they appeared in using MySQL

Tags: mysql

As part of a data science course I'm taking, I'm required to solve some (allegedly) advanced MySQL problems. Admittedly, I have no prior experience using MySQL so I'm learning as I go. I've solved some basic and intermediate problems sets on my own but am having trouble with this one.

I have an IMDB dataset comprising 3 tables:

```
actors: id, full_name, gender
movies: id, title, year, genre
cast: actor_id, movie_id, salary
```

I'm trying to find the top 5 actors with the most diverse career (i.e participation in films of different genres). I'm instructed to do this using a single query and no views.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(genre)
FROM
    movies
        JOIN
    cast ON cast.movie_id = movies.id
GROUP BY cast.actor_id
ORDER BY COUNT(genre) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

but this only gives me a list of numbers, and I'm not sure how to include the names of the actors there, or whether it's giving me the correct info (list of genres participated in by actor id).

Assuming this question complies with the forum policy (feel free to remove it if it doesn't), how would you go about accomplishing that? please explain your solution(s) so I can learn from it(them) as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea here, you just need to join it on the actors table. Also, note that 'count`counts the number of non-`null`values, and assuming that every movie has a genre, you're actually counting how many movies an actor participated in. Instead, you should use`count (distinct genre)` to count how many **different** genres of movies an actor participated it:

```sql
SELECT   a.full_name, COUNT(DISTINCT genre)
FROM     actors a
JOIN     cast   c ON a.id = c.actor_id
JOIN     movies m ON c.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY a.full_name
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT genre) DESC
LIMIT    5
```